# why do is says "[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type"?

Tags: c

**[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type**

I want to create a program that allows me to input the student full name that's why I used the function "gets" however when I run my program it will only read the input on name, age and telephone it won't read the address why is this happening ? can someone help me? I still new to this programming thing

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct data
{
    char name[10][40];
    int age[10];
    char address[10][40];
    char telephone[10][40];
}d;
main()
{

char ans='y';
int i;

i=1;
while(ans=='y'||ans=='Y')
{

    printf("Enter name: ");
    gets(d.name[i]); //this is the warning goes

    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d",&d.age);

    printf("Enter address: ");
    gets(d.address[i]); //this is where the warning goes


    printf("telephone: ");
    scanf("%s",&d.telephone[i]);//this is where the warning goes



    i++;
    printf("Enter another [Y/N]? ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);

      }
   getch();
    }
```

Comment: use `&d.name[i][0]` and similar with the other lines

Comment: There are several bugs in this code.  For instance, `scanf("%s",&ans);` will corrupt memory.  You need a character array for `%s`.  Even if a single character is entered, it will write a second character (the terminating null character).  If you want to input a single character, use `%c`.  The `gets` warnings are due to the `&` operator, which you shouldn't use in your cases.  But you shouldn't be using `gets` at all.  It's deprecated and provides no check for writing past the buffer (your `scanf` calls all have similar problems).  Use `fgets` instead of `gets`.

Comment: thank you so much ....I did tried fgets and did all the things you say but it error "[Error] too few arguments to function 'fgets'" what should i do after this?

Comment: I also try %c in ans... but it wot read it and directly terminate the program

Comment: Look at the man page for `fgets`.  It takes more arguments than `gets`.  Just match them up.  It's something you need to learn to do.  Hint:  `fgets` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: I used "fgets(d.address[i],100,stdin);" like that but it still skip... after the loop

Comment: it wont read ask input in address and skip to asking input for the telephone

Comment: Use `fgets()` and don't use `scanf()` nor `gets()`.  Mixing those causes problems.

Comment: thank you so much it did work your a life saver wish you a God bless more power!!!

Comment: my only problem now is it skip on asking input about the name after one loop...